# Как растянуть по всей оставшейся высоте элемент GridView в контейнере SrollView?

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-scrollview

Не получается растянуть по всей высоте элемент `GridView`, который помещен в контейнер `ScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_close"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/close"
                    android:text="" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                    android:text="@string/system_messages_title"
                    android:textColor="#4a90e2"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/delete"
                    android:text="" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/gvMain"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

В результате имею вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без контейнера `ScrollView` так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно задать параметры, чтобы с `GridView` был растянут по всей высоте `ScrollView`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам нашел решение в этой статье http://joerichard.net/android/expandable-gridview-inside-scrollview/ .
Автором статьи предложено реализовать класс ExpandedGridView, в котором переопределяется метод onMeasure родительского класса GridView и добавляется метод setExpanded(boolean expanded), в котором устанавливается флаг для установки высоты элемента ExpandedGridView.
Класс:

```
package com.globalsolutions.medapp.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ExpandedGridView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandedGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandedGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Добавление в layout:

```
<com.globalsolutions.medapp.ui.ExpandedGridView
   android:id="@+id/gvTypes"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:numColumns="2" >
</com.globalsolutions.medapp.ui.ExpandedGridView>
```

Активация в классе Activity:

```
ExpandedGridView gvTypes = (ExpandedGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gvTypes);
....
gvTypes.setAdapter(typesListAdapter);
gvTypes.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @Соколов, добавил.